# How to wait for a current MouseEvent EventHandler to end before accepting next MouseEvent?

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, javafx-2, mouseevent

Making progress with my board game, so on a mouse click, some tasks will be performed like playing some animations, receiving new panes for the board (I asked about this my last question, works great now), making changes to player data etc.

So, here is my EventHandler

```
grid.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
    public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
        //make changes to player data
        //receive new panes for the board
        //make some gui changes
        //play some animations
    }
});
```

Here `grid` is a GridPane object, which contains other panes for each cell of the board, panes for animation etc.

One mouse event would take 2-3 seconds to be handled. While this is going on, I saw that another mouse click would also start being handled parallel with the one already ongoing.

What I want is that another mouse event should not be processed until the first one has been completed. It would be better if, any clicks if received would be discarded.

I tried to use threading:

```
grid.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
    public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //completing the necessary tasks here
            }
        });
        t.start();
        t.join();
    }
});
```

But GUI changes would not occur if I use threading (don't know why, I tested it in many different ways, always failed to make GUI changes), so this would not work I guess.

So what could I do to not take in any mouse clicks while one mouse event is being handled? I think this question doesn't require more code, but if necessary, I would edit and add some code.

EDIT:

```
class Animations {
    public Pane getAnimationPane() {
        //returns Pane which would be used for transition
    }

    public void playAnimation() {
        //called only when the timeline transition is to be played
    }
}
```

So I made an array of the Animations class because I need a lot of such panes and need to keep a track of each one of them.

When I need to play the animation, I call the `playAnimation()` method.

Now this `playAnimation()` method is like an animation-inception.

After an animation on this pane is completed, changes are made to the board according to the player's progress, and if required... this `playAnimation()` method would call the `playAnimation()` method of several other Animation objects.

```
grid.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
    public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
        //make changes to player data
        //receive new panes for the board
        //make some gui changes
        //play some animations
        someAnimationObject.playAnimation();
    }
});
```

This could go as deep as 10-20 (more, if the grid size is large) other Animation objects being used for their `playAnimation()`.

EDIT 2:

The `playAnimation()` of `Animations` could call `playAnimation()` on 0-8 other Animations objects. And this could keep on going.

EDIT 3:

I finally sovled my problem, this is how I did it.

I added a `SimpleBooleanProperty` `isAnimating` to my `Animations` class (instance variable, i.e. non-static), set it to `false` by default.

When the timeline animation begins playing, I set it to `true`, and when the timeline animation is completed, I set it to `false`.

In the main class (say `Game`), I added a `BooleanBinding` `anyAnimating`.
I binded `anyAnimating` to `isAnimating` of each `Animations` object using the array I said I create.

```
anyAnimating = Bindings.or(anyAnimating, AnimationsObj[i][j].isAnimatingProperty());
```

And finally I used the value of `anyAnimating` as a flag in the MouseEvent EventHandler as Brad suggested.

```
grid.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
    public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
        if(!anyAnimating.get()){
            //make changes to player data
            //receive new panes for the board
            //make some gui changes
            //play some animations
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more detail about how you are launching the animations? You need to do nothing in the handler if the animations are running, which you can probably do by checking the `status` property of the animation.

Comment: @James_D, provided some more information

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure on the details here because there aren't a lot of details in your question about how the animations are managed, but this should give you the general idea.

Add a flag to your `Animations` class indicating if animations are in progress:

```
class Animations {

    private ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper animating = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper() ;

    public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty animatingProperty() {
        return animating.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public boolean isAnimating() {
        return animatingProperty().get();
    }

    public Pane getAnimationPane() {
        //returns Pane which would be used for transition
    }

    public void playAnimation() {
        //called only when the timeline transition is to be played

        Animation animation = ... ;
        animation.statusProperty().addListener((obs, oldStatus, newStatus) -> 
            animating.set(newStatus == Animation.Status.RUNNING));

        animation.play(); // etc


    }
}
```

Now you can do

```
grid.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
    public void handle(MouseEvent me) {

        if (! someAnimationObject.isAnimating()) {
            //make changes to player data
            //receive new panes for the board
            //make some gui changes
            //play some animations
            someAnimationObject.playAnimation();
        }
    }
});
```

or perhaps

```
grid.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
    public void handle(MouseEvent me) {

        grid.setDisable(true);

        //make changes to player data
        //receive new panes for the board
        //make some gui changes
        //play some animations
        someAnimationObject.animatingProperty().addListener((obs, wasAnimating, isNowAnimating) -> {
            if (! isNowAnimating) {
                grid.setDisable(false);
            }
        });
        someAnimationObject.playAnimation();
    }
});
```

Another approach would be to let `playAnimation()` accept a callback to execute when the animation is complete (or when all the animations are complete, if you are executing multiple animations).

This would look something like:

```
class Animations {


    public Pane getAnimationPane(Runnable finishedCallback) {
        //returns Pane which would be used for transition
    }

    public void playAnimation() {
        //called only when the timeline transition is to be played

        Animation animation = ... ;
        animation.statusProperty().addListener((obs, oldStatus, newStatus) -> { 
            if (newStatus == Animation.Status.STOPPED) {
                finishedCallback.run();
            }
        });

        animation.play(); // etc


    }
}
```

Then your event handling code could do:

```
// declared at instance level:
private boolean animating = false ;

grid.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
    public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
        if (! animating) {
            animating = true ;
            //make changes to player data
            //receive new panes for the board
            //make some gui changes
            //play some animations
            someAnimationObject.playAnimation( () -> {animating = false ;});
        }
    }
});
```

or

```
grid.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
    public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
        grid.setDisable(true);
        //make changes to player data
        //receive new panes for the board
        //make some gui changes
        //play some animations
        someAnimationObject.playAnimation( () -> {grid.setDisable(false);});

    }
});
```

Comment: To be honest, if I give the code about how the animations are managed, then it would add nearly 250 more lines to this question. Regarding your answer, I haven't used Listeners till now. Let's say that the `someAnimationObject` I used in the example calls `playAnimation()` on another 10 Animations objects. In the EventHandler, we check `isNowAnimating` for only the `someAnimationObject`, what if other objects are still animating? Will it still work?

Comment: No, you need to make sure the property is only set to false when everything is finished. (So it could register its own listeners, for example). If you're using `ParallelTransition` and/or `SequentialTransition` then it should be easy (just register the status listener with the "big" transition representing the whole thing). Otherwise you need to arrange only to update the property at the appropriate time. Listening to properties is a pretty fundamental concept in JavaFX: there's a [chapter in the tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) that gives an overview.

Comment: Added another solution.

Comment: This is a bit too much for me to digest, I would learn about listeners today. Would let you know once it works. Thanks

Comment: I worked it all out, see my edit. If you have any suggestions for further improvement, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be handled a couple of different ways.  One way that comes to mind is to use a simple semaphore.  To do this, you would simply declare a boolean field at the top of your class called something like isUpdating.

```
private boolean isUpdating = false;
```

When you enter your mouse click, the first thing the method would do is check to see if isUpdating is false.  If so, the next thing would be to set isUpdating to true, do the work, and then set it to false again.

```
grid.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
    public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
        if(!isUpdating){
            isUpdating = true;
            //make changes to player data
            //receive new panes for the board
            //make some gui changes
            //play some animations
            isUpdating = false;
        }
    } 
});
```

Regarding your comment on why the thread isn't updating your GUI, this is because your the changes in one thread while your UI repainting is handled in another thread.  If your anonymous thread/mouselistener is in the same class as the UI that is being updated, you can create a refresh method and call it at the end of you worker thread.

UI Class:

```
private void refresh(){
    this.revalidate();
    this.repaint();
}
```

Worker Thread:

```
grid.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
 public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //completing the necessary tasks here
                refresh();
            }
        });
        t.start();
        t.join();
    }
});
```

If your UI is in different class, you could create an external action listener and register your UI components to it.

```
public interface GridListener {
    public void gridUpdated();
}
```

Then add your listener to an object that would need access:

```
public class MyUIClass() {
    private List<GridListener> listeners;

}

public MyUIClass(){
    listeners = new ArrayList<GridListener>();
}

public void addListener(GridListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}
```

This may be more code then you're looking to write to remedy your current problem, these are just some suggestions I thought of while reading your question.

Comment: wow, so many solutions, I would try these and let you know. I did try the first one, boolean isUpdating. The boolean value would be changed before tasks complete, so it doesn't work for me.

Comment: The solution with the threads doesn't work. You should not call `join()` from the FX Application thread: it will block execution on the FX Application Thread and prevent the UI from being updated. Additionally, `revalidate()` and `repaint()` are methods that do not exist in the JavaFX API.

Comment: Oh, this is my mistake - I didn't realize the question was with JavaFX

Comment: Well the same problem occurs with AWT/Swing: you can't block the event dispatch thread.

Comment: Oh right, I agree with that.  I actually didn't even notice there was a join there, until after you mentioned it.  Regarding the revalidate and repaint though, I know they don't exist in JavaFX but I'm not not yet that familiar with JavaFX UI framework so I can't comment on a proper way... only agree that my suggestion is invalid.

Comment: I worked it all out, see my edit. If you have any suggestions for further improvement, please tell me.